# How to pass a ListView value to another page using an item button click?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have `ListView` which is populating `Id` based on `username`:

```
<Entry Text="{Binding username, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<Button Command="{Binding SearchCommand}" />
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SearchId}" 
          HasUnevenRows="False" 
          x:Name="list" 
          ItemTapped="LstItems_OnItemTapped">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell >
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" >
                    <Label x:Name="ident" 
                           Text="{Binding Id}"></Label>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>        
</ListView>

private async void LstItems_OnItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{ 
    var item = (UserDetail)e.Item;
    var newpage = new Contact(item.Id);

    await Navigation.PushAsync(newpage);
}

public Command SearchCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new Command(async () =>
        {
            var employeesServices = new EmployeesServices();
            SearchId= await employeesServices.GetUserDetailAsync(_username);

        });
    }
}

private List<UserDetail> _SearchId;           
public List<UserDetail> SearchId
{
    get { return _SearchId;  }
    set
    {
        _SearchId = value;
        OnPropertChanged();
    }
}
```

I can successfully pass the id to another page, now I have another issue, I can only pass `Id` from listview to another page when I tap on the listview.

Is it possible if I click on button `Id` directly pass on next page without tap on `ListView`?

Comment: Please edit your question to add your code behind, right now it's impossible to guess what you're aiming for.

Comment: i have edit my question help will be appreciate

Comment: So how exactly is this supposed to work? The user selects an item on the list, then clicks the button and that takes them to a new page, passing the id of the selected item to that new page?

Comment: no, what i want is user will not click item on list basically when user click on button listview retrieve Id from database i want to pass id from same button, so what i want is from one click of user Listview populte data and pass that data to next page

Comment: So 1) the user enters a name in the text box 2) they click the button, which populates the `ListView`. Could you please add the code for `SearchCommand` to your question, to see what's happening there? 3) They do something to go to the next page. What is that, and could you please add the code for that as well?

Comment: i edit my question and added search command func. See when user click on button it will populate listview and in listview it will show Id, basically that id i want to pass on next page without click on listview tap or any other button

Comment: The way it looks it's as if your `ListView` will only ever display a single entry. Is that correct? Could you also show the code of `SearchId`, please?

Comment: edited @FraukeNonnenmacher

Comment: OK, let me see if I have this right. The user enters a name and presses the button. That retrieves a list of `UserDetail`, which is bound to your `ListView`. You then want to pass an Id to the next page. That ID, is that part of `UserDetail`, i.e. `UserDetail.ID`? If yes, then how does the user select which of the entries in the list is the one that should be passed to the next page?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `SelectedItem` inside your List View like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SearchId}" HasUnevenRows="False" x:Name="list" ItemTapped="LstItems_OnItemTapped" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedListItem,Mode=TwoWay}">
```

After using this you will have current selected item of your list and you can pass that to any page!
Hope this may solve your issue.

Comment: but how can i pass this item  to other page in cs class? i mean what will be incode in cs class.? help will be appreciate

Comment: @waqaswaqas example your class A(ModelOfListView  item ) and selected item you can pass like this Navigation.PushAsync(selecteditem);

Comment: i have edit my question got another issue help will be appreciate

Comment: I strongly suggest you don't edit your question to report _other issues_. If the answer provides you a solution for what you've asked, accept it and if you're facing another issue, post a new question.